# For two charged parallel plates held back by a counterweight, why does $V_{max}$ occur at $\frac{2}{3}r_0$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, electric-fields

I did an experiment where two charged plates (one +ve, one -ve) were held in equilibrium by a counterweight. When the plates are uncharged, they are at separation $r_0$. As the potential difference is increased, the plates slowly move together (still in equilibrium as when you stop increasing the potential difference, the plates stop moving), until the voltage reaches $V_{max}$ and they are at a distance of $\frac{2}{3}r_0$. At this point, the force of attraction between the two plates overpowers the gravitational force and the plates come together.

This is what the setup looks like.

[image]

The lower plate is fixed and the upper plate is balanced by the counterweight. The counterweight force on the upper plate is in the upwards direction and the electric force on the upper plate is in the downwards direction.

I have no idea why $V_{max}$ occur at $\frac{2}{3}r_0$.

These are the equations I have been using:

$$F=k(r_0-r)$$

(gravitational force modelled as a spring, upward force for a downward displacement)

$$F=\frac{\epsilon_0AV^2}{2r^2}$$

(force due to two charged parallel plates)

I have been staring at this problem for so long and I really don't know where to start.

Comment: -1. This is the same as your question which was closed :  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/364460/for-two-charged-parallel-plates-how-do-i-show-that-the-electric-force-overpower

Comment: @sammygerbil Why does that matter... People thought it was interesting and answered my question. I hate how people here need every single question to be perfect.

Comment: Your question was closed because it did not conform with site policy, not because it was not "perfect". Asking the same question again is still a breach of site policy.

Comment: @sammygerbil In my opinion it did not breach the site policy. I did ask about a specific concept and I did show effort in answering it myself.

Comment: In the opinion of those users who had sufficient reputation to vote on the issue, it was judged to be in breach of the policy. What you asked was how to get $\frac23 r_0$. That is asking how to solve a problem, it is not asking about a specific concept.

Comment: I can't imagine that "asking how to solve a problem" is off-limits.  Can somebody please elaborate on why the original question was removed?  I thought in this case the question was well-stated and the young fellow who posted it went to some length to say he was really stumped at why the critical distance was what it was.  Ultimately the stack exchange guidelines are sufficiently ambiguous that some judgment call must be made and in this case if a student came to my office with a question formulated like this I would have worked it out just the same.

Comment: @jcandy The original question was voted to be closed because it was deemed to be in breach of the ['homework-like questions' policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/). It was subsequently deleted by the OP before posting this (almost identical) question. A judgement call *was* made by those with sufficient rep to vote to close the question. ... Yes, asking "Here is a problem, solve it for me" is *off topic* here. If you wish to change this policy you can post a question about it on [Physics Meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Of course I do not wish to "change this policy", as it makes perfect sense to me not to just do people's homework for them.  But in this case it looked to me like he had suffered enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very interesting experiment!  Let's write the force balance equation as
$$k(r_0-r) = \frac{\epsilon_0 A V^2}{2 r^2} \; .$$
Now, introduce the dimensionless length $x = r/r_0$, so the equation can be written as 
$$1-x = \frac{\lambda}{x^2} \; .$$
Here, $\lambda=\epsilon_0AV^2/(2kr_0^3)$ is a dimensionless constant that increases with the potential $V$.  Clearly, when $\lambda=0$, there is a single solution $x=1$ which corresponds to the uncharged plates.

For finite $\lambda$, the situation is interesting.  There are two roots corresponding to stable and unstable equilibria.  We can find asymptotic expressions in the limit $\lambda \ll 1$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
x_\mathrm{unstable} &\sim& \sqrt{\lambda} \; , \\
x_\mathrm{stable} & \sim& 1-\lambda \; .
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The interesting point occurs when the two roots merge.  This is the condition for the maximum value of $\lambda$ for which a stable equilibrium occurs. What we know about this critical point is that the curves $1-x$ and $\lambda/x^2$ will have only a single solution for which the former (a line) is tangent to the latter.  Thus, the condition for criticality (i.e., for the critical value of $\lambda$) is
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{\lambda_*}{x^2} \right) = -1
\quad \rightarrow \quad \lambda_* = x^3/2 \; .
$$
Inserting this expression into the force balance equation gives
$$
1-x = \frac{x}{2} \quad \text{or} \quad x = \frac{2}{3} \; .
$$
Thus, the critical distance is
$$r_* = \frac{2}{3} \,r_0\; .$$

Comment: You're welcome.  It really helps to draw the two force functions to see how the two solutions will merge as $V$ increases.  I didn't have the energy to photograph my whiteboard and post an image.

Comment: No worries, I think I understand what's happening now!

Comment: Great answer jcandy, and neat apparatus. I see a mirror for getting very fine angle measurements. I am tempted to say you answered the question "How do I show that the force equations agree with my experimental results?".  Now I am wondering if the 2/3 will emerge from a geometric argument. It seems there should be a relation here that lends itself to the physical setup. I wish I had some time :-)